# Entity Framework 4 Function Import Dataset

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have a stored procedure which does a query such as

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
```

Now, when I do a Function Import, how can I return the result as a dataset ?

does EF not support return type of a dataset  ?

Comment: Why are you wanting to use functions such as that with EF?

Answer (score 1):

No EF doesn't support return type as data set. Function import must return scalar, strongly typed entity or complex type mapped in entity model (EDMX). If you want to return `DataSet` use `SqlDataAdapter` instead.